# Mixed client and .NET library error handling.

Tags: .net, exception, vb6, interop, error-reporting

We have a .NET library that exposes COM.   Clients may be C#, or legacy VB6 code (hence the COM support).  At runtime we do not know whether the client is VB6 or .NET.

The question is how to do error handling.   .NET clients can handle exceptions but VB6 uses different error handling.  How can we transparently provide suitable error handling for both contingencies.  We need VB6 "On Error" type handling to work and we need .NET try catch to work.  Note we do not always have control over the client code.

Do we convert all raised exceptions to COM exceptions?   Thanks for any help here.

Comment: COM does not support exceptions, only error codes.  The runtime support for COM in clients often turn those error codes into exceptions, .NET and VB6 certainly do.  So hard to see your problem, did you try it?

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is in your .NET library just throw any errors and let the consuming code handle it:

```
Try
   code ...
Catch
   Throw
End Try
```

If COM catches the throw it should interpret it and same goes for .NET...